# how can i know if user is online not using membership provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

so I need to know if a user is online how can i know that? (Iam know using membership provider)

and can't find a implementation(or tutorial) for this? I understand more or less how the membership provider do it, is the best option to do it like that? or is a better way?

some example will be nice

iam usgin mvc3 in my project

Comment: One of the best ways is to use Membership.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the last activity timestamp in your users table, and update it whenever you receive any HTTP request from a logged-in user.

A user can be considered "online" if their last activity happened recently.  (the exact limit is up to you)

Comment: so when the user enter a action that is http request i update my database? i have to use ajax for that? do you have some example of how can I do that?

Comment: Just do that in the same place that you check the login ticket.  If you don't understand that, you really shouldn't be writing a login system yourself; security is hard.